# Как проверить вхождение строки в подстроку?

Tags: c#

Хочу проверить вхождение строки в подстроку:

```
string data = "6 13 24 31 35";
```

Хочу посмотреть, входит ли строка "6 1" в строку data. По идее, подстрока там есть, но хочу, чтобы проверял целые слова.

```
var data = "6 13 24 31 35";
var buff = "6 1";
if (data.Contains(buff))
     {
       // 
     }
```

Comment: Псевдокод:

    bool checkWordsPresence(String string, String substring)
    {
        String[] stringWords = string.Split(' ');
        String[] substringWords = substring.Split(' ');
        foreach (String word in substringWords) {
            if (!(word in stringWords)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

static class Program
{
    static string[]
    SplitBySpace(string s)
    {
        return s.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    }

    static bool
    Presence(string[] data, string[] buff)
    {
        if( buff.Length == 0 ) { return true; }
        int idx = Array.IndexOf(data, buff[0]);
        if( idx == -1 ) { return false; }
        return Presence(data.Skip(idx).ToArray(), buff.Skip(1).ToArray());
    }

    static void
    TestPresence(string data, string buff)
    {
        if( Presence(SplitBySpace(data), SplitBySpace(buff)) ) {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} contains {1}.", data, buff);
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} does not contain {1}.", data, buff);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestPresence("6 13 24 31 35", "6 1");
        TestPresence("6 13 24 31 35", "6 13");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понял. Полагаешь, что он из 6 13 выдерет 6 1? Так, то да. Чтобы избежать, вместо "6 1" можно запилить " 6 1 ", тогда не выдерет.

Comment: Спасибо, кеп) Я хочу, чтобы сравнение шло по полным словам.

Comment: Хм, хочешь проверить отдельно вхождение слов 6 и 1 в строку? Если нет, то я уже не знаю, что предположить.

Comment: @DanielOlivo: Тогда надо добавить пробелы в начало и конец `data` тоже. А так вообще симпатичный хак.